# Custom dropmenu boostrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I want to change the design of the dropdown-menu but I can't figure out how can i achieve this.

I would like to have the drop-down menu displayed as the same size as the container. (see screenshot below) 
I tried to modify the dropdown-menu class adding various property but nothing works
Do you have any idea?

http://zupimages.net/up/19/26/93rj.png

My code without my modifications is simply:

https://codepen.io/BigUsername/pen/zVzRjZ

Snippet:

```css
body {
  background-color: #a3d5d3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainMenu" aria-controls="mainMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="container position-relative">
                
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="mainMenu">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown show">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" href="#" id="supervisionMenu" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" style=".dropdown-toggle: :after {
    display: block;  };
    /* display: block; */
">Menu 1<i class="fal fa-chevron-down "></i>
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu show" aria-labelledby="supervisionMenu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 1</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 2</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 3</a>

                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 4</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 5</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 6</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="supervisionMenu" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Meu 2<i class="fal fa-chevron-down "></i>
                                    </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="supervisionMenu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 1</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 2</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 3</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="supervisionMenu" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu 3<i class="fal fa-chevron-down "></i>
                                    </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="supervisionMenu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="supervisionMenu" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu 4<i class="fal fa-chevron-down"></i>
                                    </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="supervisionMenu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="supervisionMenu" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu 5<i class="fal fa-chevron-down"></i>
                                    </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="supervisionMenu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="supervisionMenu" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu 6<i class="fal fa-chevron-down"></i>
                                    </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="supervisionMenu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

    </header>

<section class="blog">
        <div class="container">
            <p>Blablabla blablabla</p>
    </div></section>
```

Comment: You mean something like the mega menu, whose width is the same as the container? "Same size as the container" - I'm not sure if you refer font size or width?

Comment: what are you want to ask and give us screenshot of your need

Comment: I would like the drop-down menu (dark blue on the capture) to be the same width as the container (light blue on the capture) 
In green on the capture, that's what I'd like to get 
[link](https://www.zupimages.net/up/19/26/93rj.png)

Comment: Does anyone know how to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the `.dropdown` is displayed with relative positioning, while the `.dropdown-menu` is displayed with absolute positioning with `top: 100%;` so that the menu is displayed right under the dropdown you click.

If you want to have a full-width dropdown menu, the first thing you need to change is the `.dropdown`'s positioning. You might reset it so that the dropdown menu is no longer positioned absolutely from its parent, `.dropdown`, but from whatever next that has the relative positioning. In your case, it's the container!

Since `.dropdown-menu` is still displayed as absolute, you can easily make it as full width to whatever its relative parent is by setting its `left: 0;` and `right: 0;`.

I don't want to mess up with the *Bootstrap* default style. Hence I will introduce a new custom css class called `.mega-menu` and will add it to the `.dropdown`.

#### Layout

```html
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" />
        <div class="container position-relative">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown show mega-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggler" />
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" />
                            ...
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown mega-menu" />
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown" />
                    ...
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

#### CSS

```css
.dropdown.mega-menu {
    position: static;
}

.dropdown.mega-menu .dropdown-menu {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

#### Result

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/pL9jc7vt/13/

Comment: Thank you for the explanations and the sample code, it's perfect!
I understand better now :)
I wish you a good day